# NSTextList in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsattributedstring

Is there an equivalent for NSTextList on iOS?

On OSX i can do

```
NSTextList *list = [[NSTextList alloc] initWithMarkerFormat:@"square" options:0];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[paragraph setTextLists:[NSArray arrayWithObject:list]];
NSTextTab *t1 = [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithType:0 location:11.0f];
NSTextTab *t2 = [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithType:0 location:36.0f];
[paragraph setTabStops:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:t1, t2, nil]];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:paragraph, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
NSString *string = @"\t▪\tList item 1\n\t▪\tList item 2\n\t▪\tList item 3";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];
```

but there isn't an alternative for iOS, as all the solutions doesn't behave correctly

Comment: For only iOS developers, could you show us what's a `NSTextList`? It could help us to find the most analogical component.

Comment: it is the object used to represent an html list <ul>, <li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a late answer but it might be beneficial to people in the future.

Yes, you can in fact simply use `NSTextList` itself.

As it turns out, NSTextList has been included in iOS since at least iOS 7 (see [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextlist?language=objc) and [iOS header dumps](https://developer.limneos.net/?ios=16.3&framework=UIFoundation.framework&header=NSTextList.h)).

However, it hasn't been in the SDK for whatever reason until iOS 16.

You can copy the header from an SDK that has it into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers`.

Alternatively, I think you could forward-declare the `@interface` for the NSTextList methods you want to use.